# R: crop multiple pngs and combine them into a single plot

Tags: r, png, crop

I am plotting data into two plots like this:

```
xy <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CISCO", "JOHN"), class = "factor"), ID = c(41L, 41L, 57L, 57L), X_START_YEAR = c(1965L, 1932L, 1998L, 1956L), Y_START_VALUE = c(960L, -45L, 22L, -570L), X_END_YEAR = c(1968L, 1955L, 2002L, 1970L), Y_END_VALUE = c(960L, -45L, 22L, -570L), LC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CA", "US"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME", "ID", "X_START_YEAR","Y_START_VALUE", "X_END_YEAR", "Y_END_VALUE", "LC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
ind <- split(xy,xy$ID)
# Plots
for (i in ind){
  xx = unlist(i[,grep('X_',colnames(i))])
  yy = unlist(i[,grep('Y_',colnames(i))])    
  fname <- paste0(i[1, 'ID'],'.png')
  png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(xx,yy,type='n', xlab=NA, ylab="Value [mm]",ylim = range(c(yy,-.5,.5))) 
  i <- i[,-1]
  segments(i[,2],i[,3],i[,4],i[,5],lwd=2)
  abline(h=0)
  dev.off()
}
```

After that I am adding the resulting pngs into one png file like this.

```
library(grid)
library(png)
plots <- lapply(ll <- list.files(patt='.*[.]png'),function(x){
  img <- as.raster(readPNG(x))
  rasterGrob(img, interpolate = FALSE)
})

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

ggsave("Plots_Combined.png",width=8.5, height=11, 
       do.call(marrangeGrob, c(plots, list(nrow=2, ncol=1,top=NULL))))
```

**My question**: I was wondering if there is a way of cropping the sides of the single pngs after they are created in R? I know that you could change this in the plot loop by changing the `mar` parameters, but I was wondering if you could also do this outside after the pngs are created? I would be mainly interested in cropping the lower part of plot 1 (41.png) and the upper part of plot 2 (57.png) -> red area in the sample sketch below should be cropped. Is it possible to add a title or simple text to the resulting png (e.g. title)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can subset the image,

```
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
grid.raster(img[10:50,20:90,])
```

Comment: thank you. while this works with the R logo I cannot get R to read in my sample data, I am using the following code: `img <- readPNG(system.file("41.png", "57.png", package="png"))` and am getting an `Error in readPNG(system.file("41.png", "57.png", package = "png")) : unable to open`

Comment: @redshoe `system.file()` is really only helpful for extracting files from packages. Just try `img <- readPNG("41.png")` (assuming the PNG files are in your current working directory). You need to read them in one-at-a-time.

Comment: what I am having problems with is saving the new file in a high resolution. I am using `dev.copy(png, "outputimage.png")`
`dev.off()` which does give me only bad results. any thoughts on a better approach to save and get better results?

Comment: I would rethink the entire approach; you could edit your question with some context to explain why you decided to take this (very strange) path.

Comment: @baptiste see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560225/r-plot-several-graphs-below-each-other-into-one-window-in-a-loop where I tried to elaborate a little bit more why I wanted to do the stacking and subsequent cropping outside the loop. But if you have an idea of how to do it inside I would be glad if you would have a look at the question.